# Should I read client's stream into a string first and then parse HTTP or parse HTTP while taking input from client's stream?

Tags: java, http

I am implementing a web server and wanted to know if should I read the client's HTTP request into a string first and then parse that HTTP string, or parse HTTP while reading from the client's stream. I am using Java and did the latter. The pseudocode is something like:

1. Read the first line from the client's string
2. If the first line (HTTP status line) isn't valid throw an exception
3. Split the first line into `method`, `path`, and `HTTP` version.
4. While (read from client's string is not) EOF 
   5. Read the line 
   ...

The pseudocode for the latter option would be:

1. a <- initialize a String
2. While (read from client's string) is not EOF 
   3. Read the line 
   4. Append the line to `a`
   5. Append CLRF to `a`

And then process the string and throw exceptions if the request is not valid.

Which one do you think is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you parse it as you get it, since, for example, the size of the body will only be known to you when you get the `Content-Length` header.

You can do something like this and read line by line. (Obviously test this)

```
public static String readLine( InputStream is ) throws IOException {
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     
     int c;
     while( (c = is.read()) >= 0 ) {
          if ( c == '\r') continue;
          if ( c == '\n') break;
          sb.append( (char)c );
     }
     return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also think this is the right way to do it.